# How can I send a Twilio SMS message with longer links with query strings?

Tags: hyperlink, twilio, sms, query-string

Working with Twilio SMS text.

I am trying to send a Twilio SMS message with a hyperlink.

If the link is short it seems to go through OK. However I have some longer links with query strings and they do not seem to go through.

Is there someway to deal with longer links with query strings and twilio sms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SMS is just text. The device has to get that text and detect that is a link to make it clickable. This means, it's probably a shortcoming of the device when it doesn't display a clickable link.

However, you can work around this by using link shorteners.

Twilio's own [Link Shortening](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services#link-shortening-click-tracking) feature is currently in Public Beta and free to use during this time. The feature under Twilio Messaging Services that enables you to shorten links in your communications, with your company branded registered domain, and track engagement across SMS, MMS, and WhatsApp. Link Shortening features are embedded into Twilio Messaging API so that there is minimal implementation change required.